# Error Probabilities over Generalized K Fading Channel

Tags: matlab

1. How do I integrate the average probability of error for generalized-k?
2. How do I plot the results

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the ABER over Rayleigh fading channel, and plot the results?